# Issue uploading by ftp file

Tags: java, utf-8, ftp

I have an issue uploading file by FTP to my server. The file is a json file and I read well, there are not symbols. Here is my code to upload the file:

```
   public static void subir(){
        String server = server;
        int port = 21;
        String user = user;
        String pass = pass;

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");

        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            // Uploads first file using an InputStream
            File firstLocalFile = new File("my.json");

            String firstRemoteFile = "Folder/my.json";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Subiendo archivo a servidor...");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                System.out.println("great");
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that when I open the url that has my file I read my info with symbols, for example parecÃ­a instead parecía, GimÃ©nez instead Giménez. Can somebody help me? Thanks

I create my json manually:

```
sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
         a= "{\"results\":[";
         sBuffer.append(a);

        for (int z=0; z< myarray.size(); z++){
          if (z<(myarray.size()-1)){
              b="{\"one\":\""+ myarray.get(z).getOne()+"\",\"twoo\":\""+ myarray.get(z). getTwoo()+"\",\"three\":\""+ myarray.get(z).getThree()+"\"},";
              sBuffer.append(b);
          }
          else{
              c="{\"one\":\""+ myarray.get(z). getOne()+"\",\"twoo\":\""+ myarray.get(z).getTwoo()+"\",\"three\":\""+myarray.get(z). getThree()+"\"}]}";
              sBuffer.append(c);
          }

        }
```

Comment: The URL you are using should send a `Content-type` header that indicates UTF-8.

Comment: I don´t understand, some example? Thanks

Comment: In others json that I have in my server I don´t have any content-type, the problem is uploading by ftp

Comment: You say you access a URL. That probably means an `http:...` URL, which comes from a web server. Now, if it does not send out the correct character encoding in its `Content-type` header, you are going to get a garbled file (assuming your file is indeed in UTF-8). So you have to change whatever you are using on the server side (A servlet? A PHP script? What program returns your file?) so that it sets the proper character encoding in that header.

Comment: The problem is probably not uploading by FTP, but the fact that other JSONs are probably using the `\uXXXX` notation to encode characters so they don't have encoding problems.

Comment: Yes, the others JSON are using the \uXXX notation but this not uses, I upload the file with java to my server

Comment: So, this is the only one that has an 8-bit encoding, and this is why it will give you problems. Either change the encoding output from the URL, or change the JSON to use the `\uXXXX` format.

Comment: But if I have locally the file and I look it well, why when I upload it using java to my server the encode is bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize my comments:

A JSON file that contains characters that are not within the ASCII range (Like `é` or `ñ`) can be represented in two ways:

1. A pure ASCII file. All the "special" characters are represented by unicode escape sequences. For example, `é` is going to be represented as `\u00E9`. `ñ` is `\u00F1`. The data in the file is actually the characters `\`,`u`,`0`,`0`,`F`,`1`, but any good JSON interpreter will read that and convert it internally into the correct character.
2. An encoded file. The "special" characters are represented by 8-bit bytes according to the specific encoding you saved them as. If you chose UTF-8, the actual bytes saved in the file for `é` are `0xC3` `0xC9`. For `ñ`, the bytes are `0xC3` `0xB1`. That's how the UTF-8 encoding works - each "special" character is represented by two or more 8-bit bytes.

Now you have created a UTF-8 file and put it on your server *successfully*. It is successful because you use the *binary* method of transfer, and that means it doesn't do any encoding but just pass the bytes exactly as they are to the server.

The problem is how you read the data back.

Every HTTP URL, when it responds to a request, sends a header that tells the browser or program that reads it what type of response it returns, and *what the encoding of the characters is*.

For example, if the URL sends the header:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
```

Then the browser or reading program knows that (a) this file contains textual data, in HTML format, and (b) its character encoding is `ISO-8859-1`.

If the URL sends the header:

```
Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

Then the browser or reading program knows that (a) this file contains text in no specific format, and (b) its character encoding is `UTF-8`.

The problem in your case is that the URL serves up a file that is encoded in UTF-8. But its header says that the content type is `ISO-8859-1`.

What this means is that when the browser sees the sequence of bytes `C3` `A9` that the browser sends, which should mean `é`, it interprets them according to the `ISO-8859-1` encoding. In that encoding, each byte is a separate character. `C3` is actually `Ã` in `ISO-8859-1`, and `A9` is `©`. So what you see in your browser is `Ã©` instead of `é`. The data that was sent was *the same series of bytes*. The file was not changed. But because of the header, your browser/reader converted it internally and displayed it as different characters.

How do you solve this?

1. When you create the file, create it with the escape sequences `\uXXXX`. This will work no matter if the encoding of the HTTP response is `US-ASCII`, any of the `ISO-8859` encodings or `UTF-8`.
2. The URL is operated by some sort of web program: a servlet, a PHP script, or something. That program should send the correct `Content-type` header, certainly not something like `ISO-8859-1`. The correct content type for JSON should be `application/json`. If it sends that, it doesn't need to set a character set, because you only do that for `text/*` encodings, not for `application/*` which are considered to be byte streams. A regular browser like Firefox may or may not understand that, but a program that is supposed to read JSON URLs should understand that, and automatically interpret the JSON data as UTF-8. But if that doesn't work (because you are actually looking at the data with some text tool or Internet Explorer, not something JSON-specific), you could set the header to `text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`, OR `text/javascript; charset="UTF-8"`.

   Note that if you are accessing a direct URL such as `http://server/folder/file.json`, it means that the web server (apache, IIS, whatever) is setting the header based on its configuration settings for the `.json` suffix. In this case you have to change the server configuration for that suffix.

---

To convert the strings to escaped format programmatically when you create the JSON file, you can do one of the following (in order of best-to-worst):

- Use a proper JSON library to create the JSON.
- Use a proper string manipulation library to unescape the strings. For example, [Apache Commons `StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).
- Use a method such as this to append the characters of the string to your `StringBuffer`:

  ```
  private static void appendEscaped( StringBuffer sBuffer, String str) {
      char [] strChars = str.toCharArray();
      for ( char c : strChars ) {
          if ( c >= ' ' && c <= '~' && c != '/') {
              // Character is ASCII, append as is
              sBuffer.append(c);
          } else {
              sBuffer.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int)c));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks but I can´t create JSON with escape sequences because the Json changes programatically. The second possibility, where I have to put this header? In my Json file?

Comment: Well, you can *programmatically* create it with escape sequences. As for the second possibility, what is the program that's behind the URL you are accessing?

Comment: And how can I create this escape sequences? I don´t access to any program, I see my json in safari

Comment: myserver.com/Folder/example.json Like this I see my json

Comment: So you need to change the server configuration for files that end in `.json`. How to do that depends on the specific server, and I assume you have some control over its configuration. And to help you with the escape characters I'll need you to add the code you use to create the json, which library you use etc. to your question.

Comment: I have used the method appendEscaped and works great, thank you so much for your patience and your help!!!!